# Check for end-of-list in boost::intrusive::list without container?

Tags: c++, boost, linked-list, boost-intrusive

I'm getting started with Boost.Intrusive, specifically interested in the doubly-linked list (`boost::intrusive::list`).

This would be trivial to do in a "hand-rolled" linked list, but so far I can't find a Boost equivalent:

**Given a node that belongs to a list, how do I check to see if it represents the end of the list, without needing the owning container.**

In a hand-made list, this would be as simple as checking if the "next" pointer is NULL.

With `boost::intrusive::list`, there is the [`s_iterator_to`](https://github.com/boostorg/intrusive/blob/f44b0102b4ee9acf7b0304b3f5b27dde02297202/include/boost/intrusive/list.hpp#L1272) function, which converts a plain node to an iterator. And you can check that against `mylist.end()`, which gives the desired result, but it requires a reference to the list container itself.

I also note that using `operator++` on such an iterator simply produces a garbage value once it is moved past the end — no error or assert from Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more research and thought, it seems that there is no way to do what I want with the standard `boost::intrusive::list` functionality.

The list provided is, in fact, a circular linked list, not a linear one. So, there is no "null pointer" at the end.

The implementation seems to follow a similar design to the Linux kernel's `list.h`. You always need a reference to the container object because that contains the "head" of the circular list, which is a special node containing no user data. This is also the node that represents `end()` during traversal.

As to why this design is chosen, I haven't found any hard evidence. Seemingly, the circular list design allows a simpler implementation, with fewer branches. See, for example, [this old article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112004952/altdevblogaday.com/2011/12/06/intrusive-lists/), which says "The circular nature of the list makes inserting and removing nodes simple and branch free."

I am not fully convinced by that, since I think using "pointer-to-pointer" style handling can avoid the branches, too. But that's how it's done in `boost::intrusive::list`, regardless.